# Exception Value 'tuser' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Hi Guy's I'm new to Django. What may cause this excaption? Help me please.

model.py

```
class ParticipantModel(models.Model):

    TYPE_USER = (
        ('O', 'Онлайн трансляция'),
        ('P', 'Персональное присутствие'),
    )
    name = models.CharField( max_length=256, verbose_name='Имя')
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    position = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Должность')
    company = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Название компании')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Город')
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Электро почта')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length="50", verbose_name="Телефон")
    phonem = models.CharField(max_length="50", verbose_name="Мобильный телефон")
    www = models.URLField(verbose_name="Сайт")
    tuser = models.CharField(max_length='250', choices=TYPE_USER, verbose_name="Форма вашего участия")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = ('Участник')
        verbose_name_plural = ('Участники')


def send_marketing(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        message = "New participant"
        subject = "Updates"
        from_email = 'bakotech.events@gmail.com'
        recipient_list = ('sergey@avetisyan.com.ua')
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list)
post_save.connect(send_marketing, sender=ParticipantModel)
```

forms.py

```
class ParticipantForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta(object):
    model = ParticipantModel
```

views.py

```
class CreateParticipant(CreateView):
    form_class = ParticipantForm
    template_name = 'registraition.html'
    success_url = '/'


    def form_valid(self, form):
        VendorModel.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
        return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

This mistake has appeared after I put signals to model. I don't know what to do to step forward in django learnin and where to dig an answer. 
After i change in views to

```
def form_invalid(self, form):
    VendorModel.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
    return redirect(self.get_success_url())
```

I've catch another one mistake instead of this :

```
AssertionError at /reg
"to" argument must be a list or tuple
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    
Django Version: 1.5
Exception Type: AssertionError
Exception Value:    
"to" argument must be a list or tuple
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/mail/message.py in __init__, line 192
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.4
Python Path:    
['/home/ser/PycharmProjects/last/bakoevents',
 '/home/ser/src/userena',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/w3lib-1.3-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/home/ser/PycharmProjects/last/bakoevents',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Вск, 8 Сен 2013 22:43:35 +0300
```

Comment: You haven't posted an exception apart from question title.

Comment: Thank you, my mistake was caused by def form_valid(self, form): when i changed it to def form_invalid(self, form): everything work                                  but i've catch another one, which related to signal:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
recipient_list = ('sergey@avetisyan.com.ua')
```

to

```
recipient_list = ('sergey@avetisyan.com.ua', )
```

OR

```
recipient_list = ['sergey@avetisyan.com.ua']
```

`('sergey@avetisyan.com.ua')` is still a string with `()` wrapped around it. For python to interpret it as a tuple, you need the `,`, as `to` parameter of `send_mail` requires a `tuple` or a `list`

Comment: Karthikr excuse me, may be you know how to make that , message will contain the data, that was saved?

Comment: I am sorry. I did not get you.

Comment: The signal sent me a message, that some data has been saved to database from form. The question is : How instead of message = "New participant"  I can get to my emails data that was saved

Comment: In the method `send_marketing` can you not just change the `message="..."` ?